# Which activation function do we use in the output layer of YOLO?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification, object-detection, yolo

I have built a simple YOLO localization model in Keras like,

```
model_layers = [
    keras.layers.Conv2D( 32 , input_shape=( input_dim , input_dim , 3 ) , kernel_size=( 3 , 3 ) , strides=1 , activation='relu' ),
    keras.layers.Conv2D( 32 , kernel_size=( 3 , 3 ) , strides=1 , activation='relu' ),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D( pool_size=( 2 , 2 ) , strides=2 ),
    keras.layers.Conv2D( 64 , kernel_size=( 3 , 3 ) , strides=1 , activation='relu' ),
    keras.layers.Conv2D( 64 , kernel_size=( 3 , 3 ) , strides=1 , activation='relu' ),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D( pool_size=( 2 , 2 ) , strides=2 ),
    keras.layers.Conv2D( 64 , kernel_size=( 3 , 3 ) , strides=1 , activation='relu' ),
    keras.layers.Conv2D( 64 , kernel_size=( 3 , 3 ) , strides=1 , activation='relu' ),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D( pool_size=( 2 , 2 ) , strides=2 ),
    keras.layers.Conv2D( 128 , kernel_size=( 3 , 3 ) , strides=1 , activation='relu' ),
    keras.layers.Conv2D( 128 , kernel_size=( 3 , 3 ) , strides=1 , activation='relu' ),
    keras.layers.Conv2D( 64 , kernel_size=( 3 , 3 ) , strides=1 , activation='relu' ),
    keras.layers.Conv2D( 64 , kernel_size=( 3 , 3 ) , strides=1 , activation='relu' ),
    keras.layers.Conv2D( 32 , kernel_size=( 3 , 3 ) , strides=1 , activation='relu' ),
    keras.layers.Conv2D( 8 , kernel_size=( 3 , 3 ) , strides=1 ),
]

model = keras.models.Sequential( model_layers ) 
model.compile( loss=yolo_keras_loss , optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam( lr=0.0001 ) )
model.summary()
```

As observed, the last layer's activation function is 'linear'.

> But with regards to YOLO's output, all the values ( confidence score,
>   bounding box coordinates and class probabilities ) are normalized. So
>   should I use a sigmoid activation function or a linear activation
>   function?

I cannot find the output layer's activation function in any of resources concerning YOLO.

Comment: I think it should be linear with the same filter size and stride 1. They are normalized because of previous layers. Maybe you can put the kernel size to 1. Like in [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/4c315ea26b56c2bf20ebc240d94386c6e3cc83db/cfg/yolov3.cfg#L772)

Comment: Which Yolo version are you implementing? Do you able to use it with the linear activation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640.pdf), they use linear activation for the final layer. In section "2.2. Training" you can find:

> We use a linear activation function for the final layer and
> all other layers use the following leaky rectified linear activation...